# Populate Sharepoint column with the dates of the next 3 Thursdays

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, date

I am trying to setup a list that captures signups for a weekly meeting that happens on Thursdays. For each Thursday, there can be up to 4 people signed up on the meeting agenda. I was hoping to find a way to calculate the upcoming Thursdays so when someone goes to signup, they can choose from the next 3 weeks. Example would be:

June 11
June 18
June 25

Is it best to create a static list and reference the Thursdays manually, or can they be calculated? Also, is there a way to only allow 4 people to sign up on a given Thursday? For example:
June 11
1.
2.
3.
4.

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, it will not be possible with calculated column to do so. As you want to make the list choice column update its options depends on current date, it is beyond the reach of SharePoint list column.

**What we can do easily:**

Calculate the next 3 Thursdays. You can use a flow to update a column with the values you get. Example is here: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Take-current-date-and-display-date-of-forthcoming-Monday/td-p/195960

**What will be quite hard to do without other tools**

1. Update Choice column options
2. Only allow 4 people to sign up

It will be better for you to do these in PowerApps and create a Canvas App for this registration app. And get some workaround to fulfill your requirements.

Here is a thread may be helpful:https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Adding-More-Options-To-Choice-Column-In-The-PowerApp-User-s/td-p/136403